# How to apply different border-color for each slick slider item

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I need to apply different border-color for each slick slider item with 5 colors staring with red, i tried the code below it does not work, it applies only the first color to all items when I apply slick-slider to it.

```
<div class="slider">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
</div>

.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slider > div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

.slider > div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+3) {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
.slider > div:nth-child(5n+5) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css variables

```
<div class="slider">
  <div style='--clr:#000'></div>
  <div style='--clr:#fff'></div> 
------
</div>

.slick-item{

border:5px solid var(--clr);
}
```

Comment: slider items are added dynamically in the backend, I don't think this will work

Comment: Check it its working fine :)

Comment: Yes but more items may get added or deleted from the backend, so inline style won't work, it is a Slick carousel.

Comment: You can pass data from backend also pass color and set style variable dynamically its true way just

Comment: I am looking for a solution to apply styling ( border-color ) with a javascript loop or something, not in the backend.

Comment: Also you can define array and pass colors in array and through loop you can set style variable inline through JS

Comment: Won't work on slick

Comment: $(':not(".slick-clone"')) you can target all the slick elements and then into the map loop and through array can Style easily

Comment: Can you put the code please

Answer (score 0):

You just need to alter the nth-child settings:

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.slider>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5n+3) {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border: 5px solid pink;
}

.slider>div:nth-child(5n+5) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it, it's still not working it only applies the first color to all.

Comment: Running the snippet works so you need to show us what you have done different from the snippet in my answer.